# How to move multiple files at once to a specific destination directory?

Tags: command-line, mv

I got a bunch of files in some directory (along with many other files) that I want to move.

Luckily, all the files I want to move contain a certain identifier in their names, so I can `ls | grep IDENTIFIER` to get the exact list of files to move.

But, how can I execute `mv file /path/to/dest/folder/` at once, and not one by one (there's a lot of files to move)?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

If you want to move `ABC-IDENTIFIER-XYZ.ext` or `IDENTIFIER-XYZ.xml`, you can use:

```
mv *IDENTIFIER* ~/YourPath/
```

`*` is a wildcard for *zero or more characters*, this means *zero or more characters*, followed by `IDENTIFIER`, followed by *zero or more characters*.

This will move all the files that *contain* the `IDENTIFIER` you specified.

Answer (score 317):

You could use:

```
mv -t DESTINATION file1 file2 file3
```

The following also works, but I'm not sure if `mv` is invoked multiple times or not, as `grep` will output a new line for each match:

```
mv -t DESTINATION  `ls|grep IDENTIFIER`
```

Comment: works on linux, not sure if it will work on mac

Comment: works on mac and git bash via git for windwows.

Comment: Does not work on Mac (10.11.16 El Capitan). But you can simply put the target folder at the back, i.e. `mv file1 file2 ... destination`

Comment: -1 for second approach as it will fall for files including _new lines_

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Ah, from `man mv`, this now makes sense!: `mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...` One target dir; multiple sources--hence the `...` after `SOURCE`.

Comment: expanding to @JonathanH: if you do `mv a b -t dir` on Apple OS you get `mv: rename -t to dir/-t: No such file or directory` but it works;)

Answer (score 36):

You can use [wildcards](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/wildcards.html).

Fore example, to move all files having a `.doc` extension:

```
mv *.doc /path/to/dest/folder/
```

This will move all doc file under the current directory to the specific destination.

**Edit**

To answer the comment:

> but the list of files to move is not determined by extension. some of the files are named: `ABC-IDENTIFIER-XYZ.ext` and some just `IDENTIFIER-XYZ.ext` all having different extensions, mostly `xml` or `properties`.

```
mv *.ext  *.xml *.txt /path/to/dest/folder/
```

Comment: but the list of files to move is not determined by extension. some of the files are named: `ABC-IDENTIFIER-XYZ.ext` and some just `IDENTIFIER-XYZ.ext` all having different extensions, mostly `xml` or `properties`.

Comment: @giladhoch How about the edited one?

Comment: @gliadhoch If you are so comfortable using grep, you can see my answer above/below.

Comment: won't work since there are other `.xml` files (for instance) i do'nt want to move.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to move a set of arbitrary files (no common pattern in the names and types) you can do as Mr. Rajanand said:
first go to the directory that contains the files you want to move

```
mv file1.ext1 file2.ext2 file3.ext3 /destination/
```

In case the files are scattered in different directories, you only need to specify the path for each file in the `mv` command.

Answer (score 16):

If the files are in the same dir you can use

```
mv /path/to/source/dir/{file1,file2,*.ext1,*.ext2} /path/to/destination/
```

(tested in Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: just eliminates the need to specify full path to dir for each file

Comment: +1 very intuitive, exactly what's needed! Tested to work on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 14):

I use tuomaz's technique, but slightly modified:

```
mv file1 file2 file3 -t DESTINATION
```

I find this easier to remember and harder to screw up since it uses the same ordering as the vanilla mv operation:

```
mv file1 DESTINATION
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this command:

```
mv `ls|grep IDENTIFIER` /path/to/dest/folder
```

However, ls is not recommended for this kind of use. Use [find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/find.1.html) command instead.

Comment: `ls` is not recommended for this kind of use. If you want to list files, especially with a `grep` behind, use `find . -name \*IDENTIFIER\*`.

Comment: This answer was just to demonstrate how you can use the output of previous command in mv. As ls|grep was mentioned in the question, I just copied it.

Comment: As stated by @NorTicUs, the use of ls is ill advised. Also, files with spaces could cause a problem.

Comment: [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 5):

```
find -type f -name "[range]" -exec mv {} target-directory ';'
```

this command will move file names with any pattern/range to target-directory.

eg.

```
find -type f -name "file[1-50000]" -exec mv {} target-directory ';'
```

it will move files with names like `file1`, `file2` ... `file50000` to `target-directory`.

Comment: given the example in the question, I just want to put a note here on character classes - `[range]` (literally) will match r or a or n or g or e, so `[IDENTIFIER]` (whatever OP's identifier is) would probably not do the thing expected. Better to run `find` without `-exec` first to see what files will be operated on.

Answer (score 4):

If you have so many files to move you can actually have too many for the `mv` command (or other commands like `rm`).  I suggest using `xargs` to move each file individually in a loop like fashion. One way to get around that is to do:

```
ls -1 | grep IDENTIFIER | xargs -i mv {} /path/to/dest/folder/
```

The `ls -1` (minus one) ensures that there is only one filename on each line.  If you have hidden aliases for the `ls` command you can have multiple filenames on a single line and inadvertently move a file you did not intend to move.

Comment: This is also useful when your IDENTIFIER is not easily turned into a wildcard, or you want to use grep with a more complex regex.

Comment: +1 for xargs.  find is almost always better and safer than ls.  find . IDENTIFIER -exec mv {} /path/to/dest/folder \; (untested code) The . is for the current working directory.  The \; is to end the command to be executed.  Depending on what you're doing, you might have to add a -maxdepth 1 to keep it from recursing into subdirectories.

Comment: getting illegal option -i on mac os

Comment: On MacOS 11.4 this works
`ls -1 | grep IDENTIFIER | xargs -I % mv % /path/to/dest/folder/`

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is like this

```
mv {file1,file2,file3} DESTINATION
```

or directory

```
mv {directory1,directory2,directory3} DESTINATION
```

or both files and directories

```
mv {file1,file2,file3,directory1,directory2,directory3} DESTINATION
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` and `-exec` like this:

```
find . -name "Identifier" -exec echo mv {} <destination_path> \;
```

Comment: maybe `"*identifier*"`?

Comment: find . -name "Identifier" -exec mv {} <destination_path> \;

Answer (score 2):

You can use the output of `ls` as input to the `mv` commnad:

```
mv $(ls | grep IDENTIFIER) /path/to/dest/dir
```

The command between `$()` returns a list of the file names matching your search, and that can be provided as a parameter for the `mv` command.

Comment: [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1):

Using this command you can move multiple files:

```
mv SourceFilenames ~DestinationPath
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `fish` shell most things are fortunate. So it simple goes like this, just key in the destination as the last file.

```
mv file1 file2 file3 DESTINATION
```

Comment: this is just the normal `mv` syntax... the shell is not doing anything

Answer (score 0):

Run this below command it will move all files

```
mv * DestinationPath
```

Comment: This is already included in the other answers.