# move all .formet file from specific location?

Tags: command-line

I am replacing my current Ubuntu version version to Ubuntu 20.04 and making backup of my .cpp program  file location of my .cpp program files are in current working directory.
I am made a myprog folder on desktop of my Ubuntu machine and trying to move all .cpp file in that folder.
I there is any direct command to do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Read This [How to move multiple files at once to a specific destination directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214560/how-to-move-multiple-files-at-once-to-a-specific-destination-directory)

```
mv *IDENTIFIER* ~/YourPath/
```

`*` is a wildcard for zero or more characters, this means zero or more characters, followed by `IDENTIFIER`, followed by zero or more characters.

This will move all the files that contain the `IDENTIFIER` you specified.

Comment: Thanks it works